# Powershell issue with writing editing files that contain ' in filename

Tags: powershell, file

I wrote a script that supposed to change a certain word in a text file to the name of another file that has been dragged and dropped on onto it.

The drag and drop and recognition of the filename work without any issue.
When trying to write the file with PowerShell there is always an error message popping up.

```
powershell -Command "(Get-Content "%TemplatePath%").replace("[NAME]","!item_%%n!") | Out-File -encoding ASCII "!item_%%n!".txt"
```

the error messagethat pops up is

At line:1 char:79

- ... Templates\master.txt).replace([NAME],D:\Temp ...

Missing expression after ','.

At line:1 char:79

- ... Templates\master.txt).replace([NAME],D:\Temp ...

Unexpected token 'D:\Temp' in expression or statement..

```
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException

+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken
```

Comment: seems it is bacause -command reads a line between first two double quotes, and interpretate only

powershell -Command "(Get-Content "%TemplatePath%"
add to subquotes ` to ecrane it

Comment: I tried that but I still get the same error. I tested partially with the get content and change text first. So I open the file. Search the string and change it and it looks ok.  As soon as the text gets changed to Don't for example it gives me errors again.
For example, there is a file called main.txt and I want to change it with peter don't touch this. PowerShell -Command "(Get-Content "D:\main.txt").replace("[NAME]", "peter don't touch")

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the solution to the issue.

```
powershell -Command "(Get-Content \"%TemplatePath%\").replace(\"[NAME]\",\"!item_%%n!\") | Out-File -encoding ASCII \"!item_%%n!\".txt"
```

However, the problem is now that the if I use ASCII the single-quote in Don't is converted into an ? and looks like Don?t.

Using UTF8 works but the problem is its UTF8 with BOM.
And the program that I use to open the files does not work with BOM.
Is there any way to change the UTF8 BOM to UTF8 or to fix the ' to ? cenovertion?